# How to Make this Layout in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid-layout

I am a little stuck with creating this layout in Bootstrap 3's Grid:

http://oi62.tinypic.com/142sjt0.jpg
(Could not post image here due to rep)

This is where I got up to: http://www.bootply.com/7VrPUQwFAV

```
<div class="container">                          

<div class="row">

                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/263x263" alt=""></a>
                            <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive padding-top-30" src="http://placehold.it/263x556" alt=""></a>
                            </div>


                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/555x555" alt=""></a>

                            <div class="row">


                            <div class="col-sm-12 col-sm-offset-6">
                            <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive padding-top-30" src="http://placehold.it/555x263" alt=""></a>
                            </div>

                            </div>

                            </div>


                            <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/526x526" alt=""></a>
                            <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive padding-top-30" src="http://placehold.it/526x526" alt=""></a>
                            </div>

                            </div> 

</div>
```

Can anyone please help?

Comment: This isn't really what Bootstrap's grid system was designed for. Consider using a library like [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) which will build your grid for you and allow for responsiveness.

Comment: I did consider Masonry but the client wants the grid to stay the same, are you saying this type of layout is not possible with the grid?

Comment: You should be able to make the grid stay the same. Just define the css widths and heights (you can use `col-*-*` for widths) and masonry will fit them together. You may need to adjust the order a bit to get what you want. Not saying it's not possible with only bootstrap but is trickier.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/263x263" alt=""></a>
                 <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive padding-top-30" src="http://placehold.it/263x556" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/555x555" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                         <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/263x263" alt=""></a>
                         <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/263x263" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                         <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/263x263" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/555x263" alt=""></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Pretty good solution, just a hight issue when stacking down to med and small

Comment: make col-sm-* to col-xs-*